# Representation formula for the $\Delta^2 u =f$

Tags: convolution, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I already know the representation formula of $\Delta u =f$ is the that $u(x)$ equal to the $\phi * f(x)$, where $\phi$ is fandamental solution.

Now I have wonder konw the representation formula of $\Delta^2 u =f$ in $R^2$, is there some relative to above? And how I can find it?

I'm find that convolution the property that $D(f*g)=Df*g=f*Dg$, so I can do the same thing here, right? That is $\Delta  \phi * f(x).$

Comment: Evans - partial differential equations chapter 2. There he talks about Poisson's equation. Everything is proved there.

Comment: I'm reading this book recently. Therefore, here the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u&=g \\
\Delta g&=f
\end{cases}
$$
by applying the fundamental solution twice, i.e.
$$
u=\phi * \phi *f,
$$
provided this integral converges. The other way is done via the Fourier transformation of the equation
$$
\Delta^2u=\delta(x)
$$
and it depends on the underlying dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You can find the formula
$$
\phi(x)=\begin{cases}Cr^{4-n}\ln r \; \text{if $n$ is even and $4>n$} \\
Cr^{4-n} \; \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
by using the Fourier transform and a bit of complex analysis in the book "Generalized Functions Vol 1 Properties And Operations" in section 4 by Gelfand and Shilov.

Comment: From last exercise, I have that $u(r)=\frac{1}{8\pi}r^{2}\ln(r)$ is a fandamental solution of $\Delta  ^2 u=f$ on a plane without origin point. So $\phi$ can be choose like $u(r)$, but need to change a little to met the full plane, right?

Comment: No, the singularity is fine. With $\phi(r)=\frac{1}{8 \pi}r^2 \ln (r)$ and $r^2=u^2+v^2$, you can check that $\Delta^2 \frac{1}{8 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(u^2+v^2)^2 \ln (\sqrt{u^2+v^2})f(x-u,y-v)duduv=f$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, solving $Lu = f$ by solving $L\Phi = \delta$ and exploiting $\delta * f = f$ to say $u = \Phi * f$ is known as finding the Green's function of the operator $L$.

In your case, $L = \Delta^2$ is called the biharmonic operator. So you are looking to find the Green's function of the Biharmonic operator.

An answer to this question along with a reference is provided [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283637/greens-function-for-fourth-order-equation), along with the generalised problem for $L = \Delta^k$

Comment: From last exercise, $u(r)=\frac{1}{8\pi}r^{2}\ln(r)$ is a fundamental solution for it but without the point {0}. Is there some relative to help me do in any way?